# Facebook SDK swift: problems with fetching user data (segue)

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, sdk

It does not seem like my data is passed to the new view controller.
Indeed, it only works in the (first) view controller once logged in.
I believe there are a few mistakes in my work.
Please tell me where I'm wrong, I am a beginner so please be precise and efficient. Thanks a lot.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate
{

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil {
            //user already has access token
            self.logUserData()
        } else {

        loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

        loginButton.delegate = self


        self.Photo.image = UIImage(named: "Why subtle bckd image1")
        self.Photo2.image = UIImage(named: "Un combo unique pict")

    }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




     // MARK: PR/VAR


    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!
    var email: String!



    @IBOutlet var loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!

    @IBAction func loginButtonsend(sender: UIButton) {

        sender.setTitle("firstName", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.setTitle("lastName", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        sender.setTitle("email", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }



    @IBOutlet var Photo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var Photo2: UIImageView!






    // MARK: FACEBOOK LOGIN


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.logUserData()

    }


    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!)
    {  if error == nil {

        let fbAccessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            println("Logged in")

    } else { println(error.localizedDescription) } }



    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!)
    {
        println("User logged out.")

    }

    func logUserData()
            {
                let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me?fields=id,email,first_name,last_name", parameters: ["fields": "first_name,email,last_name"])
                graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                    if error != nil
                    {
                        // Process error
                        println(error)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        println(result.grantedPermissions)
                        println("fetched user = \(result)")
                        var firstName = result.valueForKey("first_name")
                        println("firstName = \(firstName)")
                        var lastName = result.valueForKey("last_name")
                        println("lastName is = \(lastName)")
                        var email = result.valueForKey("email")
                        println("email is = \(email)")

                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showNew", sender: self)
                    }

                }

    }
                // SEGUE:

                override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

                    if (segue.identifier == "showNew") {

                        if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? NewViewController {
                            destinationVC.firstName = firstName
                            destinationVC.lastName = lastName
                            destinationVC.email = email

                    }
                }
    }
```

}

And in my new view controller I have the following:

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController {

var firstName: String!
var lastName: String!
var email: String!


@IBOutlet var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lastNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var emailLabel: UILabel!


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if (firstName != nil) {
        firstNameLabel.text = firstName
    }

    if (lastName != nil) {
        lastNameLabel.text = lastName
    }

    if (email != nil) {
        emailLabel.text = email

    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





@IBAction func logoutButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {





    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager ()

    loginManager.logOut()





    let loginPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as ViewController



    //?

    let loginPageNav = UINavigationController (rootViewController: loginPage)





    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate



    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginPageNav



}



/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're never setting the variables from your ViewController, but instead are creating three which have the same name as the ones you should be using on logUserData. Just change to:

```
println(result.grantedPermissions)
println("fetched user = \(result)")
firstName = result.valueForKey("first_name")
println("firstName = \(firstName)")
lastName = result.valueForKey("last_name")
println("lastName is = \(lastName)")
email = result.valueForKey("email")
println("email is = \(email)")
```